# I can not start the MySQL Server from command line in windows

Tags: mysql

Whenever I write the command "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqld" the command prompt hits back with something like this:

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld"
```

141110  3:12:58 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\Dutta.lower-test
141110  3:12:58 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\Dutta.lower-test
141110  3:12:58 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
141110  3:12:58 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
141110  3:12:58 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
141110  3:12:58 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
141110  3:12:58 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
141110  3:12:58 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
141110  3:12:58 InnoDB: Operating system error number 5 in a file operation.
                InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
                InnoDB: the directory. It may also be you have created a subdirectory
                InnoDB: of the same name as a data file.
                InnoDB: File name .\ibdata1
                InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
                InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.

I'm just a beginner. May be a silly mistake. Sorry in advance !!

Comment: Have you tried starting `cmd.exe` using Run As Administrator?

Comment: Just tried it. Command line says nothing. Later I opened another cmd.exe and tried to access my MySQL user account. After giving password, it says something like "Acccess denied for user 'root'@'localhost'<using password: YES>".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context and privileges of the current user will take affect when you manually start the executable in this way.

You either need to make sure:

1. The current user has the correct permissions to all files and directories required
2. You elevate permissions of the command prompt to run as an administrator

If you have the MySQL service installed you can also use `net start MySQL`.

[This page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-installation.html) of the MySQL manual contains useful information for installing and running the MySQL server on windows.

Please remember that once you have 'started' the MySQL service (or service) you won't actually see anything, you will then need to use a MySQL client application to connect to the server and interact.

Comment: Actually I can start the server from MySQL Workbench. I've then fetched data from there using Java. But when I try to start it from the command line, it never starts.

Comment: I don't understand, if you've started the server - its started. If you can connect and read data its working. The server only starts once and you can connect multiple times using different clients. Is the server showing as running in your list of processes? if so your problem isn't starting it.

Comment: I stopped the server from MySQL Workbench and then tried to start it using cmd.exe. It never got started from cmd.exe.

Then again, I could start it from workbench. However, just a few minutes ago, after I tried to start it by running the cmd.exe as an administrator, I can not even start the server from the workbench. What may have gone wrong here ? I've checked privileges of my user account and I don't think this may be the case.

Comment: Open a command prompt and then use: net start MySQL.  If that works you should see:The MySQL service is starting.
The MySQL service was started successfully.

Answer (score 4):

I think I got it. I had the exact same problem and actually ended up uninstalling and reinstalling a couple of times; until...

```
start> CMD> c:\Program Files\MySQL Server 5.7\bin> mysql -u root -p
```

Hope its as simple for u too. I kinda laughed when I noticed.

Comment: This would be easier if you create environment variable...Please check this link: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/r-enterprise/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this answer in case it solves it for some people.
All I had to do was to:

1. Open task manager
2. Open `Services` tab
3. Find `MySQL80` service and start it.

then just start the MySQL workbench and refresh the schemas.